# Query no me trae los datos esperados

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Tengo una consulta de selección `SELECT` la cual cuando le aplico un filtro mediante `WHERE` ya no me trae nada pero sin el filtro si me trae todos los datos.

```
SELECT PC.ProductoCatalogoId, P.Nombre, PC.PrecioVenta, E.Nombre, O.NombreOpcion
FROM ProductoCatalogos AS PC
INNER JOIN Productos AS P
ON PC.ProductoId = P.ProductoId
INNER JOIN EspecificacionCatalogos AS EC
ON PC.ProductoCatalogoId = EC.ProductoCatalogoId
INNER JOIN EspecificacionProductos AS EP
ON EC.EspecificacionProductoId = EP.EspecificacionProductoId
INNER JOIN Especificaciones AS E
ON EP.EspecificacionId = E.EspecificacionId
INNER JOIN Opciones AS O
ON EC.OpcionId = O.OpcionId
WHERE PC.ProductoId = 7
```

ProductoCatalogo

[image: table]

**¿Porque cuando le pongo el `WHERE` no hace el filtro?**

Diagrama de base de datos
[image: especificacion]

Comment: Eso es porque  no hay ningun registro que cumpla que `PC.productoId = 7`

Comment: @JDev actualice la pregunta en la cual muestro que si existe en ProductoCatalogo => ProductoId = 7

Comment: Es posible que ese registro no aparezca porque no cumple las condiciones de algún INNER JOIN ¿Si quitas el where sale el registro con todas las condiciones de tu query para ese id?

Comment: @Carmen así es sin el `WHERE` me muestra todos los datos

Comment: ¿De que tipo es `ProductoId`?

Comment: @JDev entero, identity en su tabla de procedencia.

Comment: ¿y existe en la tabla origen? Pon si puedes el resultado de la query sin where

Comment: Si es un entero debería funcionar, por si es un problema del tipo de dato puedes probar con WHERE PC.ProductoId='7' y WHERE PC.ProductoId LIKE '%7%' para ver si en estos casos si sale el dato en la consulta.

Comment: Sin duda existen productos con  `ProductoId=7` pero eso no quiere decir nada cuando tienes `INNER JOIN`, si para el producto en cuestión alguna de las tablas no coincide, se invalida la consulta.

Comment: Puedes cambiar **temporalmente** los `INNER JOIN` por `LEFT JOIN`... sin duda es un problema de unión en alguna de las tablas. Si sigue sin funcionar, quita todos los `JOIN` y ve agregando uno a uno, así sabrás cuál es la tabla donde hay problemas en cuanto la agregues y ya no te arroje datos.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho acabo de actualizar el hilo, según ese diagrama todas las tablas en cuestión o las que están en esa imagen tienen campos en común, quiere decir que están perfectamente relacionadas, tengo navegabilidad, no se cual es el motivo que no vayan a coincidir y se invalide la consulta.

Comment: @A.Cedano Hice los cambios que me sugeriste si funciona pero me trae null por debajo de la tabla Productos, eso quiere decir que no me devuelve la información que necesito.

Comment: Que tengan los campos en común no quiere decir que tengan los datos en común. Por la prueba que te sugirió @A.Cedano ya te darás cuenta que tienes un problema de datos no de estructura. Revisa las tablas que retornan NULL y con ellas revisa el ID que usas para relacionarlas ¿es el correcto? ¿hay datos para el id en la secundaria?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho Efectivamente no tengo los datos en común voy a corregir la manera que persisto los datos.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho solucionado gracias a tus consejos

Comment: @PedroÁvila si ya solucionaste por favor marca una de las repuestas como solución (la bandera a la izquierda de cada comentario), que me leí la pregunta completa, la analicé, pensé en mi respuesta... y luego me di cuenta de que ya estaba solucionado...